# Delphi - Implementation of "sepia" routine for an arbitrary color

Tags: delphi, colors, image-manipulation, delphi-2006, colorize

I've seen the odd routine for converting an image to a sepia-tone version, like this one:

```
function bmptosepia(const bmp: TBitmap; depth: Integer): Boolean;
var
color,color2:longint;
r,g,b,rr,gg:byte;
h,w:integer;
begin
  for h := 0 to bmp.height do
  begin
    for w := 0 to bmp.width do
    begin
//first convert the bitmap to greyscale
    color:=colortorgb(bmp.Canvas.pixels[w,h]);
    r:=getrvalue(color);
    g:=getgvalue(color);
    b:=getbvalue(color);
    color2:=(r+g+b) div 3;
    bmp.canvas.Pixels[w,h]:=RGB(color2,color2,color2);
//then convert it to sepia
    color:=colortorgb(bmp.Canvas.pixels[w,h]);
    r:=getrvalue(color);
    g:=getgvalue(color);
    b:=getbvalue(color);
    rr:=r+(depth*2);
    gg:=g+depth;
    if rr <= ((depth*2)-1) then
    rr:=255;
    if gg <= (depth-1) then
    gg:=255;
    bmp.canvas.Pixels[w,h]:=RGB(rr,gg,b);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(from [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1794)) but I need something that does this for an arbitrary color - i.e. it will take an image, presumably form a gray-scale version of it, and then apply the new colour to the image.  It's the last bit I'm having trouble with - i.e. the replacement of the shades of gray with the color of interest.

So I need

```
procedure BmpToOneColor (const bmp      : TBitmap ;
                               depth    : Integer ; 
                               NewColor : TColor) ;
```

(I have no idea why the original was written as a boolean function).

Comment: Also, use [`ScanLine`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ScanLine) instead of [`Pixels`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.Pixels). Latter is very inefficient when you're working with more pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base algorithm is just adding fixed offsets to each color channel of the gray value. We can generalize this so that the `NewColor` parameter determines the offset for each channel. Notice that `depth` becomes redundant and you can leave it out entirely.

```
rbase:=getrvalue(NewColor);
gbase:=getgvalue(NewColor);
bbase:=getbvalue(NewColor);
base:=min(rbase,min(gbase,bbase));
rdepth:=rbase-base;
gdepth:=gbase-base;
bdepth:=bbase-base;

rr:=r+rdepth;
gg:=g+gdepth;
bb:=b+bdepth;
if rr < rdepth then
    rr:=255;
if gg < gdepth then
    gg:=255;
if bb < bdepth then
    bb:=255;
```